# ansible use vars in vars from with_items loop

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I am trying to use a variable from with_item to create a fact whose name changes:

```yaml
- name: get ABC Root CA pem from chamber
  shell: AWS_PROFILE={{aws_profile}} chamber read -q secrets abc_ca_{{ item }} | awk 'NR==2 { FS="[ \t+]"; print($2); }' | base64 -d | gunzip
  changed_when: false
  delegate_to: localhost
  vars:
    ansible_become: no
  with_items: "{{ abc_environments }}" # see defaults/main.yml
  when: ('chamber' in chamber_installed.stdout)
  register: abc_returned_environment
  tags:
      - service-discovery

- name: set ABC root ca pem secrets
  set_fact:
    aws_secrets: "{{ aws_secrets|default({}) | combine( {item.item: item.stdout} ) }}"
  with_items: "{{abc_returned_environment.results}}"
  when: ('chamber' in chamber_installed.stdout)
  tags:
      - service-discovery

- name: Write aws_secrets ABC root CA file
  vars:
    env: "{{ item }}"
  copy:
    content: "{{ aws_secrets.(lookup('vars', env )) }}\n"
    dest: /etc/prometheus/abc_{{ item  }}_file_sd/ca_{{ item  }}.pem
    owner: prometheus
    group: prometheus
    mode: 0600
  with_items: "{{ abc_environments }}"
  when: ('chamber' in chamber_installed.stdout)
  tags:
      - service-discovery
```

How do I get the `content` line to behave something like this?

```yaml
content: "{{ aws_secrets.abc_ca_dev }}\n"
```

Where `abc_environments` is set as:

```yaml
abc_environments:
  - dev
  - qa
  - int
  - staging-green
  - staging-blue
  - prod-green
  - prod-blue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turn out to be actually quite simple:

```
- name: Write aws_secrets ABC root CA file
  copy:
    content: "{{ aws_secrets[ item ] }}\n"
    dest: /etc/prometheus/abc_{{ item  }}_file_sd/ca_{{ item  }}.pem
    owner: prometheus
    group: prometheus
    mode: 0600
  with_items: "{{ abc_environments }}"
  when: ('chamber' in chamber_installed.stdout)
  tags:
      - service-discovery
```

Also handles dashes in the variable names.